# Loop through files in a folder, and open the pdf's

Tags: mac, bash, terminal

I have a folder of pdf files I am reading, how can I loop through them and open them all?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you really want a loop

```
for file in *.pdf; do
    open $file
done
```

This will open each file in a seperate preview window.  To get them all in the same window

```
open *.pdf
```

will work as well.

Comment: how can you open multiple pdfs in the same window?

Comment: Use the second command above.  If you open the sidebar, it will show the individual files.  This can be done either from the menu bar, or the "View" menu.  Moving you mouse over a multi-page document in the sidebar will allow you to click on the curvy arrow and display each page.  You can also page down through each page of all the documents, in order.